# Arrays & Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Looking for some help with arrays and pointers and explanation of what I am trying to do.
I want to create a new array on the heap of type Foo* so that I may later assign objects that have been created else where to this array. I am having troubles understanding what I am creating exactly when I do something like the following.

```
Foo *(*f) = new Foo*[10];
```

Also once I have created my array how do I access each element for example.

```
(f + 9)->fooMember(); ??????
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Foo *(*f) = new Foo*[10];
```

The parentheses in the declaration are unnecessary, so this is the same as:

```
Foo **f = new Foo*[10];
```

In any case, the `new Foo*[10]` allocates space for ten `Foo*`s and leaves them uninitialized.  It returns a pointer to the initial `Foo*` in the array (the zeroth element), which you assign to `f`.

To access elements of the array, you simply use subscripting:

```
f[0] = new Foo;
f[0]->fooMember();
```

Remember that anything you create using `new[]` must be freed once when you are done with it by calling `delete[]` on the pointer.  For example:

```
delete[] f;
```

This does *not* delete the elements pointed to by the `Foo*`s in the array.  If you create `Foo` objects using `new`, you must `delete` them *before* you delete the array.  For example, to free the element we created above:

```
delete f[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to access the individual elements without using the [] operator but with pointer arithmetic how would this look?

Comment: @Thomas:  `f[0]` is just shorthand for `*(f + 0)`, so for example, you can do `(*(f + 0))->fooMember()`.

Comment: Thanks. What roll does the first brackets with * play?

Comment: @Thomas: The opening paren causes the dereference-and-child operator `->` to operate on the *object* as opposed to the pointer. Just like the rest of pointer logic, it's confusing as heck at times.

Comment: @Thomas: why don't you want to use the square brackets? They are there for a reason: simplifying the code when you perform random access into arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of pointers using the following code:

```
Foo** f = new Foo*[10];
```

Then access the elements with:

```
f[9]->fooMember();
```

Be sure to clean up afterwards:

```
delete[] f;
```

Thanks.

Comment: All correct, and yet I am missing a comment on the fact that if those three lines are pasted together into a program with no extra code the system will most probably die (as no actual `Foo` objects were created)

Answer (score 1):

When you have this situation, you might find the following code snippet useful:

First the initialization:

```
Foo** f = new Foo*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    f[i] = new Foo;
}
```

Then to access each element in the f array which is what you asked, but you won't be able to do so unless you allocate memory properly for each member by calling the constructor as done above:

```
f[9]->fooMember();
```

Finally, to keep things tidy and to prevent memory leaks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete f[i];
}
delete[] f;
```

Comment: You should use `std::for_each` over explicitly written loops.

Comment: @Billy ONeal - That's assuming you're going to use STL.  Granted that's almost always true, still that's an assumption.  The for loop is still legal and valid C++.

Comment: @Khnle: True. However, just because something's possible or valid does not mean it's the best method for accomplishing things. Algorithm calls are always better than explicit loops.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: can you write the equivalent `for_each` calls? Is the code going to be any simpler or more complex than the plain `for` loop? I tend to use the simplest approach, the one that leaves with the easier to read code, and to be fair I would have to think on how to write those two `for_each` calls... so I guess that ease of writing also affect my decisions on what to write. In this particular case I would do just as Khnle has done.

Comment: @Billy I can only say - b*ll*cks.

Comment: @Billy:  I _might_ use `for_each` once we have C++0x and either (a) lambda functions or (b) `default_delete`; until then, though, a for-loop is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers aren't very C++ish. How about

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> > f;
f.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>(whatever, arguments, you, need));
// ...
f[9]->fooMember();
// ...
```

No manual cleanup needed :-)

Comment: Except of course that shared_ptr is not yet part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @Neil Yes, but I hope every competent programmer is smart enough to google `shared_ptr` and find a solution. If `std::shared_ptr` doesn't work, `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` should do the trick :)